# DownloadManager works for API 30 but no for API 27

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I am trying to download a pdf file from the server (I have the url), and I am trying this solution

```
fun downloadPDF(url: String?, fileName: String): ResponseStatus {
        val uri = Uri.parse(url)
        val downloadManager = context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager?
        val request = DownloadManager.Request(uri)
        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(
            DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE
        )
        request.setTitle(fileName)
        request.setDescription("Android Data download using DownloadManager.")
        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)
        request.setMimeType("*/*")
        if (downloadManager == null) {
            return ResponseStatus.Error( context.getString(R.string.download_error) )
        }
        downloadManager.enqueue(request)
        return ResponseStatus.OK(uri)
}
```

this works for API 30 but not for API 27 and I don't know why.
Can someone help me please?

UPDATE:
I think that this can be a permissions problem because I tried again in API 27 and see this in the log    `java.lang.SecurityException: No permission to write to /storage/emulated/0/Download/file name12-34: Neither user 10080 nor current process has android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE.`

Comment: You could set an actual mime type. Or not at all.

Comment: Yes, I can try it

Comment: it doesn't look like that worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the problem, I changed this line
`request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, fileName)` for a uri that I parse with the address of the download folder and the file name, and I set it with `request.setDestinationUri (destinationUri)`

```
val destination = context.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).toString() +
                "/" + fileName
val destinationUri = Uri.parse("$FILE_BASE_PATH$destination")
```